# Session Authentication Fails on Express Server After Google OAuth Login

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, session, oauth

I'm developing a MERN stack application with a React frontend hosted on Surge (`https://thestudyapp.surge.sh`) and an Express backend hosted on Render (`https://study-app-server.onrender.com`). I've implemented Google OAuth for authentication using Passport.js. The OAuth flow appears to work correctly—I can log in and see the user's details logged on the backend, indicating that serialization and Google OAuth authentication work as expected. However, when I attempt to access protected routes after authentication, specifically `/current-user`, I receive a `401 Unauthorized` error, suggesting that the session is not persisting across requests or the user is not recognized as authenticated for subsequent requests.

#### Environment:

- **Frontend**: React app hosted on Surge
- **Backend**: Express server hosted on Render
- **Authentication**: Google OAuth with Passport.js

#### Issue Details:

After a successful Google OAuth login, the user's details are logged on the backend, and the user is serialized correctly. However, when accessing the `/current-user` route to fetch the current user's details, the request fails with a `401 Unauthorized` status. Despite the apparent success of the authentication process (as indicated by the backend logs), the session does not seem to persist or the user is not recognized as authenticated on subsequent requests.

#### Backend Configuration Snippets:

**Session Configuration in Express:**

```js
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URI }),
  cookie: {
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none"
  },
}));
```

**CORS Configuration:**

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "https://thestudyapp.surge.sh",
    credentials: true, // Allow sending cookies from the frontend
  })
);
```

**Passport Initialization:**

```js
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**Passport Google OAuth Strategy Configuration:**

```js
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: `${process.env.BACKEND_BASE_URL}/auth/google/callback`
}, async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      const client = await connectDB();
      console.log("Google profile ID:", profile.id);

      let user = await client
        .db()
        .collection<Account>("accounts")
        .findOne({ googleId: profile.id });

      if (!user) {
        // If the user does not exist, create a new user.
        const response = await client
          .db()
          .collection<Account>("accounts")
          .insertOne({ googleId: profile.id });

        // Fetch the newly created user
        user = await client
          .db()
          .collection<Account>("accounts")
          .findOne({ _id: response.insertedId });
      }
      console.log("User:", user);
      done(null, user || undefined);
    }));
```

**Route for `/current-user`:**

```js
accountRouter.get("/current-user", (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.json(req.user);
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: "User not authenticated" });
  }
});
```

#### Attempts to Resolve:

- Verified that `withCredentials: true` is set for all Axios requests from the frontend.
- Confirmed CORS configuration on the backend to include credentials and the correct origin.

Despite these checks, the `/current-user` route consistently returns a `401 Unauthorized` error after a successful login. It seems like the session is not being maintained between the OAuth flow and subsequent requests.

#### Questions:

1. Are there known issues with session persistence for Express applications hosted on Render when using Google OAuth and Passport.js?
2. Could the issue be related to the specific configuration of cookies or the session store with `connect-mongo`?
3. Is there a step I'm missing in ensuring that the authentication state persists across requests in a React/Express application setup?

Any insights or suggestions to debug this issue further would be greatly appreciated.

---